# "addTrailingSlashesToUrls" Config option being ignored

Tags: craft3

I have set the `addTrailingSlashesToUrls` option in the config file `config/general.php` as below:

```php
<?php
/**
 * General Configuration
 *
 * All of your system's general configuration settings go in here. You can see a
 * list of the available settings in vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/GeneralConfig.php.
 *
 * @see \craft\config\GeneralConfig
 */

use craft\helpers\App;

return [
    // Global settings
    '*' => [
        // Default Week Start Day (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday...)
        'defaultWeekStartDay' => 1,

        'enableTemplateCaching' => false,

        // Whether generated URLs should omit "index.php"
        'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,

        // Control Panel trigger word
        'cpTrigger' => 'admin',

        // The secure key Craft will use for hashing and encrypting data
        'securityKey' => App::env('SECURITY_KEY'),

        // Whether to save the project config out to config/project.yaml
        // (see https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/project-config.html)
        'useProjectConfigFile' => false,

        'addTrailingSlashesToUrls' => true,
    ],

    // Dev environment settings
    'dev' => [
        // Dev Mode (see https://craftcms.com/guides/what-dev-mode-does)
        'devMode' => false,
    ],

    // Staging environment settings
    'staging' => [
        // Set this to `false` to prevent administrative changes from being made on staging
        'allowAdminChanges' => true,
    ],

    // Production environment settings
    'production' => [
        // Set this to `false` to prevent administrative changes from being made on production
        'allowAdminChanges' => true,
    ],
];
```

And now I expect to be able to visit `sitename.test/recipes` and have it redirect to `sitename.test/recipes/` but it doesn't.

Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing [`addTrailingSlashesToUrls`](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/config/general.html#addtrailingslashestourls) does, is to ensure that any and all URLs generated by Craft have trailing slashes added to them.

To redirect incoming requests without trailing slashes, you'll need to set up your own redirects (ideally this should happen at the web server level, i.e. in your Nginx config, Apache `.htaccess` file or the like).